# Division between complex number to himself

Tags: math, division, complex-numbers

Refers to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) and some other calculators:

- 1i / 1i = -1
- i / i = 1

My questions are:

1. Why division between complex number to himself does'nt return the value 1?
2. The both expressions should be the same, so why the results are diffrent?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I asked this question as a part of my android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be aware of what the first expression means. In particular, where are the hidden parentheses.

`1i/1i` is in fact `1 * i / 1 * i`, which is `(((1 * i) / 1) * i)` when all the parentheses are added.

Then, step by step, you get `((i / 1) * i)`, then `(i * i)`, which is `-1`.

This is very different from `(1i)/(1i)`, which is effectively `1`.